# Active Directory Group Members don't match member attribute

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm working with a vendor who needs to use LDAP queries to pull information on our Active Directory.  The query pulls from the 'members' attribute of the AD Group directly.  However it only pulls 8 of the 20+ users in this group.  If I look at the group's Members tab, I can see all of the users, and they work without an issue.  I switch to the Attributes tab and scroll to the members entry view the values which shows only 8 of the users. The LDAP query only pulls these 8 and not the rest of the users.
How do I fix this so the attribute and members list match without deleting/recreating the group?  If I delete and recreate it would take down our production environment.

I've tried removing and re-adding users to the group and it does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that this group is the primary group for the users that you don't see in the `member` attribute. Members don't appear in the `member` attribute if the group is the primary group. I don't know why this is... blame Microsoft.

To find those users, look at the `primaryGroupToken` of the group. It will be a number. Then search for users that have that value in their `primaryGroupId` attribute.

Usually, the primary group is the built-in Domain Users group, which always has a `primaryGroupToken` of `513`. So to find users of that, you would use this LDAP query:

```
(primaryGroupId=513)
```

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygroupid), the `primaryGroupId` attribute is indexed, so you don't need any other criteria.

If you want to learn more about how memberships work, I wrote an article a while ago about [What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html)

Comment: You definitely pointed me in the right direction with this.  I found that what I can use instead of the 'memberof' attribute, is the 'primaryGroupID' attribute for any users who have this group set as their primary.  I also found that the 'primaryGroupID' is actually the last 4 digits of the 'objectSID' attribute of the group.

Comment: Correct, although it's not necessarily the last 4 digits. It could be more or less. It's the last segment of the SID, after the domain portion of the SID.